# How do I install v4l2loopback on raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, kernel, streaming-video, v4l2

Normally I get v4l2loopback by simply

```
git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback
cd v4l2loopback
make && sudo make install
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=10,11
```

and now I get:

> modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found.

It seems to be a problem with the kernel headers. After looking online, no one had a fix just lots of suggestions that don't work or v4l2loopback support saying it's a raspbian issue.

$ uname -a

> Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l
>   GNU/Linux

How do I get v4l2loopback working on raspbian Jessie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Build:**    to build the kernel module run:

$ make

this should give you a file named "v4l2loopback.ko", which is the kernel module

**Install:**      to install the module run "make install" (you might have to be 'root' to have all necessary permissions to install the module).

if your system has "sudo", do:

$ make && sudo make install

if your system lacks "sudo", do:

$ make

$ su
(enter root password)

make install

exit
**Run:**

//Dont forget to give this below command as root user:

depmod -a

load the v4l2loopback module as root :

modprobe v4l2loopback

using sudo use:

sudo modprobe v4l2loopback